# Multiple values for OptionSettings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I need to add multiple securityGroups to my EB-Environment. This is a part of my template for EB Environment:

```
  Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
  Properties:
    ...
    OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
        OptionName: SecurityGroups
        Value: ...
```

### I tried to:

**Use SecurityGroups 2x**

but the latter overrides the preceding value

```
      - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
        OptionName: SecurityGroups
        Value:
          - !Sub ${EnvironmentPrefix}-ssh
      - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
        OptionName: SecurityGroups
        Value:
          - launch-wizard-1
```

**Use an array**

but it ends up with an error:

> Value of property Value must be of type String

```
      - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
        OptionName: SecurityGroups
        Value:
          - !Sub ${EnvironmentPrefix}-ssh
          - launch-wizard-1
```

How can set multiple SecurityGroups for **'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration) you can pass a comma separated list of security groups as the value.

> You can provide a single string of comma-separated values that contain
>   the name of existing Amazon EC2 security groups or references to
>   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup resources created in the template. If you use
>   Amazon VPC with Elastic Beanstalk so that your instances are launched
>   within a virtual private cloud (VPC), specify security group IDs
>   instead of a security group name.

So:

```
  Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
  Properties:
    ...
    OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
        OptionName: SecurityGroups
        Value: sg-1,sg-2,sg-3
```